# Getting Parsley 2.x working with Bootstrap 3 correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, parsley.js

I am using `Twitter Bootstrap 3.1.1` with `Parsley v2.0.0-rc3`. I made it mostly work apart from `classHandler` option.

I have HTML like this:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="username">User Name</label>
    <input class="form-control" id="username" name="username" required="" type="text" value="">   
</div>
```

And run Parsley like this:

```
$("#register_form").parsley({
    successClass: "has-success",
    errorClass: "has-error",
    classHandler: function(el) {
        return $(el).closest(".form-group");
    },
    errorsWrapper: "<span class='help-block'></span>",
    errorTemplate: "<span></span>"
});
```

Everything works fine, but success / error classes are applied to wrong element. After the page is loaded, I get this:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="username">User Name</label>
    <input class="form-control" id="username" name="username" required="" type="text" value="" data-parsley-id="5043">
    <span class="help-block" id="parsley-id-5043"></span>
</div>
```

And when validated, the result is this:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="username">User Name</label>
    <input class="form-control has-error" id="username" name="username" required="" type="text" value="" data-parsley-id="5043">
    <span class="help-block filled" id="parsley-id-5043">
        <span class="parsley-required">This value is required.</span>
    </span>
</div>
```

However, I expect something different:

```
<div class="form-group has-error">
    <label class="control-label" for="username">User Name</label>
    <input class="form-control" id="username" name="username" required="" type="text" value="" data-parsley-id="5043">
    <span class="help-block filled" id="parsley-id-5043">
        <span class="parsley-required">This value is required.</span>
    </span>
</div>
```

I have verified using `alert` that the function runs. But I am new to jQuery and JavaScript, so I do not know how to debug it any further and fix it.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You should try:

```
classHandler: function(el) {
    return el.$element.closest(".form-group");
}
```

The el is an object from parsley (I have seen it using chrome dev console) and he has a $element field with the JQuery element :)

Comment: Can you spare a few notes about how did you look at the `el` object in development console?

Comment: put a breakpoint in the classHandler function then play with "el" ;) Your breakpoint defines the scope of your function or it seems so

Answer (score 2):

Full code working:

```
$("#register_form").parsley({
    successClass: "has-success",
    errorClass: "has-error",
    classHandler: function(e) {
        return e.$element.closest('.form-group');
    },
    errorsWrapper: "<span class='help-block'></span>",
    errorTemplate: "<span></span>"
});
```