# Parsley JS not working with bootstrap-select

Tags: bootstrap-4, parsley.js, bootstrap-select

i created a form with https://parsleyjs.org/ and it works fine with `text input` and it displays error. But when it comes to `bootstrap-select` it doesn't show any error.
Here is an small example below

https://jsfiddle.net/sanoj908572/jdo6reaf/2/

**HTML**

```
<div class="form-group">
     <label for="tit">Title</label>
     <input type="text" name="tit" class="form-control" id="tit" required>
</div>
<div class="form-group w-50">
     <label for="edu">Brand</label>
     <select name="brd" class="selectpicker form-control" id="edu" data-live-search="true" data-live-search-style="startsWith" data-parsley-required>
             <option data-display="Select Brand">Select Brand</option>
             <option>Audi</option> 
             <option>BMW</option> 
             <option>Chevrolet</option>
             <option>Fiat</option> 
             <option>Ford</option>
             <option>Hindustan Motors</option> 
     </select>
 </div>
```

**JS**

```
  $("#adform").parsley({
  errorClass: 'is-invalid text-danger',

  successClass: 'is-valid', // Comment this option if you don't want the field to become green when valid. Recommended in Google material design to prevent too many hints for user experience. Only report when a field is wrong.
  errorsWrapper: '<div class="input-group"></div>',
  errorTemplate: '<small class="form-text text-danger"></small>',
  trigger: 'change'
})
```

**CSS**

```
.was-validated .form-control:invalid, .form-control.is-invalid {
    border-color: #dc3545;
    padding-right: calc(1.5em + 0.75rem);
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' fill='%23dc3545' viewBox='-2 -2 7 7'%3e%3cpath stroke='%23dc3545' d='M0 0l3 3m0-3L0 3'/%3e%3ccircle r='.5'/%3e%3ccircle cx='3' r='.5'/%3e%3ccircle cy='3' r='.5'/%3e%3ccircle cx='3' cy='3' r='.5'/%3e%3c/svg%3E");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center right calc(0.375em + 0.1875rem);
    background-size: calc(0.75em + 0.375rem) calc(0.75em + 0.375rem);
}

.was-validated .form-control:valid, .form-control.is-valid {
    border-color: #28a745;
    padding-right: calc(1.5em + 0.75rem);
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 8 8'%3e%3cpath fill='%2328a745' d='M2.3 6.73L.6 4.53c-.4-1.04.46-1.4 1.1-.8l1.1 1.4 3.4-3.8c.6-.63 1.6-.27 1.2.7l-4 4.6c-.43.5-.8.4-1.1.1z'/%3e%3c/svg%3e");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center right calc(0.375em + 0.1875rem);
    background-size: calc(0.75em + 0.375rem) calc(0.75em + 0.375rem);
}
```

now how do i show error for `Bootstrap-select`

[image]

Comment: Did you check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22217735/getting-parsley-2-x-working-with-bootstrap-3-correctly ?

Comment: my question is how to i make parsley work with bootstrap-select.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bootstrap-select` plugin triggers the [`changed.bs.select`](https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/options/#events) event on change. Adding the event in [`triggerAfterFailure`](http://parsleyjs.org/doc/#ui-for-field)

```
$("form").parsley({
  ...
  triggerAfterFailure: 'focusout changed.bs.select'
})
```

**CSS for invalid bootstrap-select**

```
/* On Invalid */
.selectpicker.is-invalid ~ .dropdown-toggle {
  border-color: #dc3545 !important;
  color: #dc3545 !important;
  outline: none !important;
}

.selectpicker.is-invalid ~ .dropdown-toggle:focus {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.2rem rgba(220, 53, 69, 0.25) !important;
}

/* On valid */
.selectpicker.is-valid ~ .dropdown-toggle {
  border-color: #28a745 !important;
  color: #28a745 !important;
  outline: none !important;
}

.selectpicker.is-valid ~ .dropdown-toggle:focus {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.2rem rgba(40, 167, 69, 0.25) !important;
}
```

### **Fiddle**

**Unclosed Issues**

- https://github.com/snapappointments/bootstrap-select/issues/2304
- https://github.com/snapappointments/bootstrap-select/pull/1988

Comment: i added the css but it doesn't work, what is the change in fiddle you have done, how it validates.

Comment: @sanojlawrence I have provided the working fiddle link already

Comment: yes the fiddle works, can you explain what wrong in my code, so that i can make changes because adding only css `classes` doesnt solve my problem.

Comment: There is nothing wrong in your code. The problem is there are no validation classes available in `bootstrap-select`. So we have to make it on our own

Comment: and in `parsley` after entering value (selecting option) it should turn green, but your fiddle doesn't

Comment: the validation triggers error but doesn't show success after selecting, however it works perfectly in fiddle. added `js` and `css`

Comment: can you check fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/sanoj908572/a0yfk4nx/1/ after validation shows invalid when i select option it doesn't truns success.

Comment: @sanojlawrence Its [working](https://jsfiddle.net/aswinkumar863/9tev0drp/1/). Are you sure about what is `data-parsley-min`, `data-parsley-group` and `option`'s `value` attribute? Please read [`parsley`](https://parsleyjs.org/doc/index.html#validators-list) and `bootstrap-select` documentations carefully

Comment: is there a way i can use `ID` to trigger instead of `changed.bs.select` something lie `changed.bs.#select` because i have two `select` in a form. If one is filled and other is not filled and the form is submitted the second doesn't show error